# Deletar/Destruir tabela html via javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Quando eu precisava apagar completamente uma tabela ou qualquer outro elemento html eu usava jquery `$.empty()` no elemento pai onde o elemento estava.

Existe alguma forma nativa no javascript que faça essa remoção de elementos html.

```
ex: tabela.delete()
```

No caso da tabela ela é toda gerada na DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa declarar um método para remover o elemento pelo ID dele:

```js
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

E então, assumindo que sua tabela tem o ID `minha-tabela`, você a pode remover com:

```
document.getElementById("minha-tabela").remove();
```

Ou então, selecionar ela por alguma classe:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("table-sm").remove();
```

Por alternativa a todos estes acima, você também pode zerar o HTML do elemento:

```
document.getElementById("minha-tabela").outerHTML = "";
```

---

Fonte desta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id).

Answer (score 1):

O método [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) do jQuery remove todos os os elementos **de dentro** de um elemento (*child nodes*), mas mas mantém o elemento em si no DOM.

Uma forma similar em JavaScript puro, seria esvaziando a propriedade `.innerHTML`:

```
elemento.innerHTML = '';
```

Por outro lado, se você quer remover o próprio elemento (não apenas os seus `filhos`), o que não tem a ver com o `.empty()` do jQuery mas com o `.remove()`, em JS puro seria esvaziar a propriedade `.outerHTML`:

```
elemento.outerHTML = '';
```

Ou usar a API [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), que não tem suporte no Internet Explorer:

```
elemento.remove();
```

Mas existe um [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) compatível com IE9+.